# Android Device Monitor not launching inspite of running the computer in the administrative mode ?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I have tried many ways to get my Android Device Monitor get started. However nothing seems to be working. Can anyone please help

Comment: Did you enable it in Tools>Android>EnableADB Integration :)

Comment: Yes. I did. @ManojFrekzz